# Save Android CAMERA API without INTENT

Tags: java, android, camera

Hello i have the whole code, but i want to save the snaps automatically and release camera to back preview. I don't know how to do that :/  It's taking the snapshot but don't save neither release camera.

Thanks for the hlep guys!!

```
package com.velcisribeiro.xcamera;

+imports

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Camera cameraObject;
private ShowCamera showCamera;
private ImageView pic;
public static Camera isCameraAvailiable(){
    Camera object = null;
    try {
        object = Camera.open();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
    }
    return object;
}

private PictureCallback capturedIt = new PictureCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data , 0, data .length);
        if(bitmap==null){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not taken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "taken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        cameraObject.release();
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
    cameraObject = isCameraAvailiable();
    showCamera = new ShowCamera(this, cameraObject);
    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    preview.addView(showCamera);
}

public void snapIt(View view){
    cameraObject.takePicture(null, null, capturedIt);
}
}
```

And the other one is:

```
public class ShowCamera extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private SurfaceHolder holdMe;
private Camera theCamera;

public ShowCamera(Context context,Camera camera) {
    super(context);
    theCamera = camera;
    holdMe = getHolder();
    holdMe.addCallback(this);
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try   {
        theCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        theCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        theCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I was building my own camera implementation, I just used the code provided by the Zxing library. It works really well and you can easily modify it to do what you'd like:
https://github.com/zxing/zxing

Answer (score 0):

You need to add following two lines in surfaceDestroyed callback for releasing camera.
theCamera.stopPreview();
theCamera.release();
And for saving image change onPictureTaken callback.
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

```
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data , 0, data .length);
    if(bitmap==null){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not taken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "taken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    //Add code to save image
    cameraObject.release();
}
```

Also have a look on following URL for better understanding.
http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/01/how-to-use-android-camera-to-take.html.

Comment: Yes but the camera is stopped after taked the snapshot :/ Can't release to restart preview anyway.